# PHP-separate the variables value from the position of character '+'

Tags: php

I have variable of type varchar having values `$pointmoney=356+2311;`

pointmoney is a field in database from where i am retreiving this value .

now i have separte two variable `$point and $money`

where i want to store `$point=356 and $money=2311` from `$pointmoney=356+2311`.(i.e separate values from '+').

If any 1 knows any similar function then pls answer.
hope i ellaborated well to understand my query . if anything is unclear pls feel to comment .

Comment: You should `explode('+',$pointmoney);`

Answer (score 3):

Use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$pointmoney = "356+2311";
list($point, $money) = explode('+', $pointmoney);
```

Answer (score 1):

you [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_string_explode.asp) function like

```
$pointmoney = "356+2311";

$arr_money = explode("+",$pointmoney);


echo $point = $arr_money[0];
echo $money= $arr_money[1].
```

hope this will sure help you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` reference [PHP explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
   $pointAndmoney = "356+2311";
   list($point,$money) = explode('+',$pointAndmoney); // now you have different variable for each
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode("+","54+99");

$point = $arr[0];

$money = $arr[1];
```